# how to select all memeber vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i have problem with sql

i want to select all memeber that there feesdate is <  1 mounth ago

my code:

```
Private Sub ShowData()
     Dim dtToday As DateTime = Date.Today
     dtToday = dtToday.AddMonths(-1)

     DataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 30
     DataGridView1.Font = New Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular)
     conn.Open()
     If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
         conn.Close()
     End If

     With cmd
         .Connection = conn
         .CommandText = "select f_id,f_recno,f_name,f_workout,f_feesmode,f_fees,f_feesdate from
 tbl_memberfees where f_feesdate > " & Date.Today.AddMonths(-1) & ""
     End With
     da.SelectCommand = cmd
     dt.Clear()
     da.Fill(dt)
     DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
     conn.Close()
     datagridviewcontrol()
End Sub
```

Comment: What ***data type is f_feesdate***? I also recommend adding parameters as your `sql` syntax is wrong as well... You would need `'` around your date. If you had parameters this wouldn't be an issue... On another note, `feesdate is < 1 mounth ago` your query is wrong. `f_feesdate >` that should be `f_feesdate <` if you want it less than a month ago, currently that is greater...

Comment: the  type f_feesdate is text ..can halp or make small exemple

Comment: I would strongly recommend making a change to that column for a datetime/date column data type ***otherwise*** you would need to convert and or cast this to a correct type to do the comparison... With this in mind you can store anything in there, think about your data types. I would strongly search Google about this as well as using parameters. When you get this understanding work on constructing your query the right way...

Comment: What problem you have?

Comment: thank you  zaggler for replay i will see that

Comment: i want to select all momber there datefees is < as 1 mounth ago for use it as notice to inforem them for Pay

Comment: @amine02 welcome! I could have posted a solution, but the concern is more than just the query itself if you know what I mean...Because when you address the parameters and your datatypes then the query would make sense and everything else would fall into place...

Comment: sorry but im new in sql

Comment: @amine02 No do not be sorry at all, it's a learning process and its also the ***correct*** way to do it.

Comment: here my new try


    Dim dtToday As DateTime = Date.Today
        dtToday = dtToday.AddMonths(-1)

        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from tbl_memberfees where f_feesdate < '" & Format(dtToday, "MM-dd-yyyy") & "'", conn)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "tbl_memberfees")

        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

but i have this error
The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the less than operator.

Answer (score -1):

Try this... Because you are storing the data in SQL as a varchar. You should do the conversion in SQL.

```
Private Sub ShowData()
 Dim dtToday As DateTime = Date.Today
 dtToday = dtToday.AddMonths(-1)

 DataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 30
 DataGridView1.Font = New Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular)
 conn.Open()
 If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
     conn.Close()
 End If

 With cmd
     .Connection = conn
.CommandText = 
"selectf_id,f_recno,f_name,f_workout,f_feesmode,f_fees,f_feesdate 
from tbl_memberfees 
where CONVERT(DATETIME, f_feesdate , XXX)> " & Date.Today.AddMonths(-1) & ""
End With
 da.SelectCommand = cmd
 dt.Clear()
 da.Fill(dt)
 DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
 conn.Close()
 datagridviewcontrol()
End Sub
```

where XXX is the current format of the date stored as string.

Comment: Also you should prob just change the varchar to a date time.

Comment: Does anyone read the comments anymore? Also your command text isn't valid sql. If you did read the comments I discussed that...

Comment: it's ok now i change the type from text to dateandtime 
and olso your code is works 
thanks all thanks for replay

Comment: why is my command text not valid - not only that, however I answered the question despite the comments.

Comment: Because you are missing the `'` around the date object, grab that and run it in sql and see if it works... Should be `where CONVERT(DATETIME, f_feesdate , XXX)> '" & Date.Today.AddMonths(-1) & "'"`, which wraps the date otherwise it's not valid.

Comment: opps, you are correct I did forget the single quotes. I normally use sprocs in either case. Let us rookies answer sometimes :)